# JEE shared library in WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, shared-libraries, weblogic

I am porting my application to WebLogic as an Enterprise Library so that my EJB and MDB can invoke code in it.

I have chosen a EAR packaging for both say Lib1.ear and Lib2.ear which contains APP-INF/lib directory and have 100's of jars in both. I also have updated the `MANIFEST.MF` of both to contains `Specification-Version` and `Implementation-Version`. Both are deployed successfully and available to be used.

Now I updated my ear which contains my EJB and MDB and added following in `weblogic-application.xml`;

```
 <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>Lib1</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>18</wls:specification-version>
</wls:library-ref>
<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>Lib2</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>18</wls:specification-version>
</wls:library-ref>
```

But when I am deploying my EAR (which constains EJB etc) it fails on the first step complaining that it does not find an `interface` which is defined and packaged in `Lib1.ear` shared lib as my one of my EJB implements that. I have enabled debug log but I am unable to find any information from WebLogic which directs me to the right path. All my EJB are initialising with the remote name etc but then I get a single line error in my log followed by a `ClassNotfoundException`;

```
<28-Nov-2017 15:26:18,005 o'clock GMT> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: com.xyz.abc.runtime.debugger.DebuggerListener
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:38)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:168)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:198)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:160)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:781)
        at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:530)
        at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5690)
        at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:528)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
        at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
        at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:262)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:134)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
        at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.internal.PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.strutsLookupInternal(PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.java:43)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:108)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:707)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:141)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:108)
        at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
        at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:219)
        at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.abc.runtime.debugger.DebuggerListener
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.loadAndAppendOtherLinks(WSEEModuleHelper.java:164)
        at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotations(WSEEModuleHelper.java:186)
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.processAnnotations(WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.java:121)
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.merge(WSEEEJBToolsModuleExtension.java:87)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.MergeModuleFlow.compile(MergeModuleFlow.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
        ... 116 more
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I would be surprised if it is actually possible to use a WAR file as a library.

Comment: You should probably include the libraries as jar files in the project not as WAR. Unless I am mistaken if you have EJBs in a WAR then they are only visible within that WAR (local) and connect be accessed remotely.

Comment: @SteveC yes it is possible to package shared lib as WAR but the limitation is that shared lib packaged as WAR can only be referenced by other WARs not EAR. So now changed my package from WAR to an EAR. Put a dummy EJB just so that I can deploy.

Comment: @ChadNC I have an existing EAR which contains EJB, MDB and WAR's. All of these reference to many of my core libraries which currently resides on disk and added to server CLASSPATH directly (dirty solution!). My requirement is that I want to move all jars from loose directory to proper JEE Shared lib and reference them via deployment descriptors from my EAR. This way I can manage my libs via WebLogic console instead of updating directories etc.Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Have you tried deploying the WARs separately in Weblogic as a library instead of an application? I don't know if it would work but it might since the application should be able to see the deployed libraries, I've been wanting to try that myself but have never had a real reason to.

Comment: I have updated my packaging as EAR now...still the same... classes are just missing...

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer for others so that they can get this done quickly. If shared lib is packaged as WAR can only be referenced by other WAR's not an EAR. So I updated my package to be an EAR. As I stated above all I wanted to share my libs which are POJO's I had to use following structure and my EAR was able to see classes successfully.

```
    LIB1.ear
    META-INF
        application.xml
        weblogic-application.xml
        MANIFEST.MF
    APP-INF
        lib
            *.jar (all pojo's here and WebLogic will add these into Application Classpath)
    dummyejb-1.0.0.jar  (just so that I can deploy this ear in server otherwise it won't continue)
```