# Weblogic deployment interception

Tags: deployment, shared-libraries, weblogic12c, intercept

This question is a continuation of my work to make the application proper JEE where I have successfully moved my POJO's as JEE shared library (EAR). For more details on packaging see [JEE shared library in WebLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535352/jee-shared-library-in-weblogic?noredirect=1#comment82117222_47535352)

Now I like to intercept the deployment of this library i.e. I like to run some code present in EAR implements some sort of an `interface` like `javax.enterprise.deploy`. In the implementation, I like to install some data records if Update of the JEE library is detected and if I am unable to load the data items I would like to throw an exception causing WebLogic to reject the update (i.e. fail the update so that I can keep the last known good state)

Actually, I looking for something similar to OSGi Bundle Activator hook in JEE container? Do we have anything. I looked at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPRF/api_intro.htm#DEPRF112 the specs but this is more of remote deployment tools instead of something embedded in the library.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research my conclusion is that there is no way JEE gives you this control. The JEE Specs above is about how to write your own tool which can perform remote deployments and WebLogic seems to have implemented the specs well. So answer is `NO` there is no way we can intercept the deployment and run code as part of the deployment